# How does Traefik choose from ingresses with coliding prefixes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, traefik-ingress

I'm containerizing an existing application and I need a basicauth for a single path prefix, currently I have the following Ingress configuration:

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: service-auth
spec:
  basicAuth:
    secret: service-auth
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: service
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "traefik"
    cert-manager.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/frontend-entry-points: http, https
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-entry-point: https

spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - fqdn
    secretName: fqdn-tls
  rules:
    - host: fqdn
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: service
                port:
                  name: http
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: service-auth
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "traefik"
    cert-manager.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/frontend-entry-points: http, https
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-entry-point: https
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: default-service-auth@kubernetescrd

spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - fqdn
    secretName: fqdn-tls
  rules:
    - host: fqdn
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /admin/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: service
                port:
                  name: http
```

This seems to be working, but I just want to make sure - can I rely on the `/admin/` prefix to be always picked up by the second ingress or is there a chance that it will be picked up by the ingress with `/` prefix and thus displayed without basicauth?

Comment: As you can reed in [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/):
"`Prefix`: Matches based on a URL path prefix split by `/`. Matching is case sensitive and done on a path element by element basis. A path element refers to the list of labels in the path split by the `/` separator. A request is a match for path _p_ if every _p_ is an element-wise prefix of _p_ of the request path."

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/):

Each path in Ingress must have the appropriate path type. Paths without an explicit `pathType` will not be validated. There are three supported path types:

> `ImplementationSpecific`: With this path type, matching is up to the IngressClass. Implementations can treat this as a separate  `pathType`  or treat it identically to  `Prefix`  or  `Exact`  path types.
>
> `Exact`: Matches the URL path exactly and with case sensitivity.
>
> **`Prefix`: Matches based on a URL path prefix split by `/`. Matching is case sensitive and done on a path element by element basis. A path element refers to the list of labels in the path split by the `/` separator. A request is a match for path *p* if every *p* is an element-wise prefix of *p* of the request path.**

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#examples) is also a link for examples in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

We had a simliar question recently (using traefik as our ingress controller) and apart from the official documentation linked in @kkopczak's answer, we also checked the logic in traefik.

In the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) under **Multiple matches**:

> In some cases, multiple paths within an Ingress will
> match a request. I**n those cases precedence will be given first to the
> longest matching path**. If two paths are still equally matched,
> precedence will be given to paths with an exact path type over prefix
> path type.

In the traefik controller, there is a [concept of priority](https://github.com/traefik/traefik/blob/6622027c7cbea6656dfb11a2285e012c9ee6a052/docs/content/routing/routers/index.md#priority):

> To avoid path overlap, **routes are sorted, by default, in descending
> order using rules length.** The priority is directly equal to the length
> of the rule, and so the longest length has the highest priority.

Or, directly in the [code](https://github.com/traefik/traefik/blob/679def0151af12f46c5d8eb3c86fcaeb602efda2/pkg/rules/rules.go#L60):

```
if priority == 0 {
    priority = len(rule)
}

route := r.NewRoute().Handler(handler).Priority(priority)
```

Here the `rule` is the path, e.g `/admin/`.
And you can actually set the priority using the following annotation

```
traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.priority
```

The Priority of the default backend is per defintion [the least important rule](https://github.com/traefik/traefik/blob/1048348ae65497feb4a05e090f0ac910586c7996/pkg/provider/kubernetes/ingress/kubernetes.go#L253) - `math.MinInt32`:

```
      rt := &dynamic.Router{
            Rule:     "PathPrefix(`/`)",
            Priority: math.MinInt32,
            Service:  "default-backend",
        }
```

So yes, you can rely on this solution.